# what is the difference of production gear and base gear on openshift?

Tags: node.js, openshift

I'm using OpenShift to host my node web applicatoin.

I'm just wondering what's the difference between production gear and normal gear?

If i decided to change gear, how do I do it? apart from backup/restore to different gear.

many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All production gears can be deployed to both the US and Europe hosting regions, while the basic small gear can only be deployed in the US hosting region. Also, all production gears have higher CPU performance than the basic small gear.

To change gear sizes, scaling, and/or deployment region you can use `rhc app create` to clone your existing application. The command below will create a complete copy of the original app and create a new, non-scalable version of the app using a medium gear in the default US region:

```
$ rhc app create <new_app_name> --from-app <existing_app_name> --no-scaling --gear-size medium
```

The command below will create a complete copy of the original app and create a new, scalable version of the app using small.highcpu gears in the Europe region:

```
$ rhc app create <new_app_name> --from-app <existing_app_name> --scaling --gear-size small.highcpu --region aws-eu-west-1
```

For more info on scaling and available gear sizes check out the OpenShift [Developer Portal](https://developers.openshift.com/en/overview-platform-features.html).